# Use the Child Layout as Template for List View

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I've a `ListView`(not subclass) like `View`. For ListView we need to use another layout file to inflate as template. But, in my one I'm trying to use the child `ViewGroup` as the template.

```
<com.aashakil.ExListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/listLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >     

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelModuleCode"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/CourseName"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/labelCourseType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CourseType"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</com.aashakil.ExListView>
```

I can get the child from `Java` by `ExListView.getChildAt(0)`. But, I can't use it multiple time or as a template. For this I have to remove it from the parent every time which I don't want.

So, is there any way to inflate the child of that `ExListView` instead of another file.

Comment: Hey, Can you also show the activity and adapter code?

Comment: @ravi It's not `ListView` as I've mentioned.